# Solr php extension on zend server ce make fails

Tags: php

I've got curl, and libxml which are dependencies of the solr extension

But pecl could not realize that, so I did,

```
pecl install -n solr
```

knowing that I have set the correct php.ini, ext_dir ..etc, the make fails with the following error:

```
/tmp/pear/temp/solr/solr_functions_helpers.c:24:2: error: unknown type name ���zend_json_globals���

make: *** [solr_functions_helpers.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```